# Horde Groupware in Synology

Tags: php, synology, horde

Need information to install Horde on Synology.
I heard there is a Horde package for Synology, Can someone help me find the link.
I am new and tried in many ways to find it myself before asking.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that you tried "many ways" to find it considering it's listed in one of the main [Synology 3rd party repositories](http://www.synocommunity.com/packages).

However, it is listed as a private beta right now for use on the Synology - and I'm assuming if you were part of the private beta, you would have known how to get the package already. [image: Horde]

Comment: Thank you. Every question is a silly one for subject matter experts. I am new. I came accross this page, added the repo in synology still the package doesnt show in the package list. Pleas help. How to be part of beta.

Comment: It's a "private beta".. meaning, it's not available to the general public. If you want to be part of the beta, try talking to the Horde dev team not a bunch of non-related sysadmins here on serverfault.

Comment: Horde Development team says, "I have no idea what synology is".
I communicated with info@horde.org to get this reply.